# How can I tightly wrap a Column of widgets inside a Card?

Tags: flutter

I have a page of my app that consists solely of a `Card` that holds a `Column` at the end of which is a `MaterialList`. Even if my list only has one or two items, the Card extends its vertical space to the bottom of the screen rather than stopping at the end of the list items.  The [Column documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) suggests this is normal Column behavior ("Layout each child a null or zero flex factor (e.g., those that are not Expanded) with unbounded vertical constraints").  I thought wrapping the list in a `Flexible` might achieve my desired effect but when I tried I got the following error:

```
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
I/flutter (11469): When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is
I/flutter (11469): in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a
I/flutter (11469): flex on a child (e.g. using a Flexible) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining
I/flutter (11469): space in the vertical direction.
I/flutter (11469): These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child
I/flutter (11469): cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.
```

I'm clearly misunderstanding something about how this layout is supposed to work.

Here is sample code of what I have now as the body of the `Scaffold` for this page:

```
new Container(
// Outer container so we can set margins and padding for the cards
// that will hold the rest of the view.
alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
margin: new EdgeInsets.only(top: style.wideMargin),
padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: style.defaultMargin),
child: new Card(
  child: new Column(
    children: [
      new CustomHeader(), // <-- a Row with some buttons in it
      new Divider(),
      new MaterialList(
        type: MaterialListType.twoLine,
        children: listItems, // <-- a list of custom Rows
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

)

How can I have a Card that tightly wraps a `Column` of widgets?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

By default, `Column` expands to fill the maximum vertical space.  You can change this behavior by setting the `mainAxisSize` property to `MainAxisSize.min`, which causes the `Column` to take up only the minimum amount of vertical space it needs to fit its children.

Comment: It seems like that behavior of `Column` has changed in the new release. If the inner widget is a `ListView`, you can ask it to take up only the minimum space by setting `shrinkWrap` to `true`.

Comment: This worked like a charm for building a gradient button that expands when in a column with stretch set on cross-axis but looks small when not in a column.

Answer (score 9):

Wrap widget may come to rescue if anyone wants to shrink its list, which exacts similar to
@Adam answer

```
body: Container(
        child: Card(
          child: Wrap(
            direction: Axis.vertical,
            spacing: 10,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('One'),
              Text('Two'),
              Text('Three'),
              Text('Four'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

but this Wrap can do the job of both Row & Column if you add Column for Axis.vertical & Row for Axis.Horizontal. **Also you can add equal spacing to all inbetween widgets which is missing in Column & Row**

Comment: If you're ok with letting the `Flex` class layout things for you, shouldn't a `Row`/`Column`'s [`mainAxisAlignment`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/MainAxisAlignment.html) property be sufficient to add equal spacing between widgets? (Specifically `spaceAround`/`spaceBetween`/`spaceEvenly`)

Answer (score 2):

If Row or Column is your root widget,
use `MainAxisSize.min` on root widget.

If Another widget is the root, then
wrap that root widget in `Center` widget.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `mainAxisSize: min` never seemed to work.  I always got the stupid error that it didn't know what to do.  To fix, I just resorted to ListView with shrinkWrap: true

```
return ListView(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  // background is red
  children: [
     ...
  ]
)
```